# Get container directory more easily

Tags: bash, shell, pwd, basename, dirname

I have a bash script here:

```
$GOPATH/
     src/
     build.sh
```

and in build.sh I have:

```
export GOPATH="$(cd $(dirname "$BASH_SOURCE") && pwd)"
```

is there a shorter way to get the containing dir of build.sh?

Answer (score 2):

To get the directory where the script is located, use this:

```
readlink -f $(dirname $0)
```

As said in the bash man page, `$0` is set to the name of the file.

`readlink -f` gets the absolute path of that directory.

Comment: Unfortunately `readlink -f` is not very x-platform, it doesn't work on OSX sadly

Comment: `realpath` would also work, but I don't think realpath is available out of the box on OSX either, lame lol

Comment: Will not work for subscript executed inside original script

Answer (score 0):

Extending the BASH_SOURCE idea, check to see if it contains an absolute path; if so, use it directly, otherwise prepend PWD. Afterwards, strip off the trailing slash and anything following it, leaving just the containing directory:

```sh
case ${BASH_SOURCE[0]} in
  ( /* )
        p=${BASH_SOURCE[0]}
        ;;
  ( * )
        p=${PWD}/${BASH_SOURCE[0]}
        ;;
esac

p=${p%/*}
printf "%s\n" "$p"
```